# Rails: Retrieve all records that have the same variable value in a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been asked to right a report of users that have the same billing address. Of course, I don't have a list of addresses to compare against, so is there a way to return all records that share an address with another record?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi how about something like

```
Model.find_by_address(Model.find_by_id("1").address)
```

if you need a list to compare

```
Model.all(:group => :address).map(&:address)
```

Comment: Although this solution depends on the amount of data to process. ActiveRecord will instantiate Model objects, even if there are 20000 addressees.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I can think of is doing it through SQL query.

```
Addresses.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE addresses.addr_line_1 IN (SELECT addr.addr_line_1 FROM addresses AS addr)......")
```

Hope this helps.